# Express get request code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' when sending response

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, get, response

So this is a common problem in Express, this question is asked a lot but none of them worked for me,
I have a get request with axios to my express server to check the auth status of the user with firebase, everything works fine, but this error shows in my console, here's the code:

**Server.js**

```
const firebaseDb=require("firebase/database");
const firebaseAuth=require("firebase/auth");
const path = require('path');
const express= require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const db=firebaseDb.getDatabase();
const auth=firebaseAuth.getAuth();
app.get('/checkAuth',(req, res)=>{  

firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.      
    return res.status(200).send("auth ok");

  } else {
    // User is signed out
    return res.status(404).send("auth error");
  }
});
});
```

So the error is exactly where my `return res.status(200).send("auth ok");`
I tried `return res.sendStatus(200);` still same problem,
some solutions suggested to add the `return`before the res.send but again it didn't work, ANY IDEA ABOUT THIS ERROR?

Comment: That problem can't be caused by that code alone.

Comment: @robertklep console is showing it at the same line and exactly at res.`send`

Comment: Yes, that's the code that's _triggering_ it, but there's other code that's _causing_ it, and you're not showing that. So, for example, are you using custom middleware in your app?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I'm using body-parser, I'm gonna edit my code so you can see all my server code !

Comment: Also, `onAuthStateChanged` looks like it may be an event emitter, in which case it could emit events multiple times, which could cause your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with the Firebase library, but I can read documentation.

`onAuthStateChanged` is an event emitter that can fire events for multiple situations: the current user signed in, or they signed out. Because it's an event emitter, it can emit multiple events, and that's your problem: for each event, you're calling either `res.status(200).send()` or `res.status(404).send()`. This works for the first event that is emitted, but the second event will trigger a `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error because you already sent back a response.

Besides that, you're creating a new event handler for *every* request to `/checkAuth`, which will eventually cause your app to run out of memory, because these event emitters remain active. 1000 requests to `/checkAuth` means you create 1000 event handlers.

If I understand the documentation correctly, it looks like you can use `auth.currentUser` instead, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
app.get('/checkAuth', (req, res) => {  
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.      
    return res.status(200).send("auth ok");
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    return res.status(404).send("auth error");
  }
});
```

Comment: I was reading the documentation it worked just fine, much THANKS !
 However for those who could implement the auth with `onAuthStateChanged` without any errors, it's the best solution.